# to read a big excel file in java

Tags: excel

I am trying to read a excel file through java apache poi in netbeans  containing about 8000 columns and 1200 rows for which I am getting the following exception. I have also tried to increase the heap size in netbeans with –Xmx2048m but it doesn’t help me out.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3039)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur$CurLoadContext.attr(Cur.java:3060)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxHandler.startElement(Locale.java:3250)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.reportStartTag(Piccolo.java:1082)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseAttributesNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1802)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseOpenTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1521)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseTagNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1362)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXMLNS(PiccoloLexer.java:1293)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.parseXML(PiccoloLexer.java:1261)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.PiccoloLexer.yylex(PiccoloLexer.java:4808)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yylex(Piccolo.java:1290)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.yyparse(Piccolo.java:1400)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.piccolo.xml.Piccolo.parse(Piccolo.java:714)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.load(Locale.java:3439)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1270)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1257)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.WorksheetDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.read(XSSFSheet.java:188)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.onDocumentRead(XSSFSheet.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onDocumentRead(XSSFWorkbook.java:300)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:221)
    at testdoc.Testdoc.main(Testdoc.java:26)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 49 seconds)
```

The line no 26 is

```
File excel = new File ("E:\\Project\\Rapid out\\"+filename+""+type+".xlsx");
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        Line 26::   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
                XSSFSheet ws = wb.getSheet("Sheet2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using InputStream, can you try with File:

> `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(excel);`

From [POI Guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

> When opening a workbook, either a .xls HSSFWorkbook, or a .xlsx XSSFWorkbook, the Workbook can be loaded from either a File or an InputStream. Using a File object allows for lower memory consumption, while an InputStream requires more memory as it has to buffer the whole file.